# Silverlight Combobox setting the selected item to selected item of datagrid

Tags: silverlight

I have 2 silverlight controls on a form; datagrid which is bound to list of items, combobox which is bound to list of values.

Scenario...when a user selects a row on the grid i want to set the update the combobox so that the value of a property of the selected item in the datagrid is displayed.

My combobox looks like

<                ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Description" x:Name="cbTopics" 
                          Margin="141,170,0,0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                           SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem.Topic.Description, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

In the load event i set the itemssource of the combo to the list of values.  I would like to set the combobox to be description of the item selected in the datagrid.  The items in the datagrid is a collection of objects

object Code
the object Code has a property Topic which has a property of Description (hence why I am trying SelectedItem.Topic.Description).

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong here? I am trying to setup the relationship between the datagrid selected item and the combobox through xaml only.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,36,0,0"
              Name="cbTopics2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="399"
              SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=dataGrid1, Path=SelectedItem.Topic.Description, Mode=TwoWay}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Description"
              SelectedValuePath="Description" />
```

The above was the solution.